# How to disable new Angular project from automatically adding files to git

Tags: intellij-idea, angular-cli, settings

I want my Intellij IDEA not to add all files to Version Control System (VCS) - it happens when **new Angular project is created**, however I want to add it manually later.

```
Settings > Version Control > Confirmation > When files are created > Do not add
```

This setting is not working, the same configuration is in

```
File > Other Settings > Settings for New Project > Version Control > Confirmation > When files are created > Do not add
```

Answer (score 2):

As I know `Intellij IDEA` the same as `VisualStudioCode` or `Webstorm` when creating new project they automatically create a git repository.

Probably the only way to prevent this is using this command via terminal:

```
ng new projectName --skipGit=true
```

Doc: https://angular.io/cli/new